# Strange error when reading a CSV file through method

Tags: python-3.x

So, I've got a CSV file (league.csv') in my directory that I want to access through Python.

When I do this:

```
with open('league.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
  csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

  next(csvReader)

  for line in csvReader:
    print(line[0])
```

It works great. But when I try to make it into a function it doesn't work:

```
def createLeague(csv):

  with open(csv, 'r') as csvFile:
      csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

      next(csvReader)

      for line in csvReader:
        print(line[0])
  return
```

If I call this using:

`createLeague('league.csv')`

I get the error

```
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

This makes no sense because type(csvFile) is not str, and I'm doing exactly the same as above?

Could someone help me, I'm getting really frustrated!

Thanks!

Comment: local inheritance of functions inside the function seems not matched.

Comment: If you accept one of the answers, it will help mark this as solved so that others won't need to try and help.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See inline comment what goes wrong.

```
import csv                           # "csv" variable at "with open..." overwrites
                                     # cvs module.
from csv import reader               # required to use the function "reader" from csv.

def createLeague(csv):               # "csv" variable overwrites cvs module.

  with open(csv, 'r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = reader(csvFile)      # skip the csv. here and it works for you.
    next(csvReader)

    for line in csvReader:
        print(line[0])
  return
```

Alternatively:

Below example with changed ***csv filename*** does not overwrite the ***csv module*** that you just have loaded. The mix-up triggers the error to occur.

```
import csv
#from csv import reader

def createLeague(csv_file):

  with open(csv_file, 'r') as csvFile:    # changed variable "csv" filename.

    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

    next(csvReader)

    for line in csvReader:
        print(line[0])
  return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, guys! I'll think about not using library names as variables!

Comment: Counts also for the python build-in names ;p

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the name of the library as the name of the variable in the function definition.